# How to check if Salesforce Org is affected with Log4j2 vulnerability?

Tags: issue

How to check if Salesforce Org is affected with  Log4j2 vulnerability?
Below are the link where Issue was reported.

https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/826

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000DyuuUSAR

If anyone has done analysis, Feel free to share their experience

Comment: RE the concerns about DataLoader in that trailblazer feed, I dug around the GitHub repo and it looks like 4 days ago they updated the Log4j version to 2.15.0 from 2.14.1: https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/commit/c7eada43acc40685f3f46f9492e19696fef52f81

Comment: Of note, this patched version pf Data Loader is not what's downloaded from setup yet.  You can read the discussion in the issues section of the repo for more info.

Comment: @VictorLockwood Thanks for sharing the information. Does it mean should we stop using data loader temporary till we get clarification from Salesforce side?

Comment: ashitsalesforce says in the issues conversation on the GitHub that you should be fine since Data Loader doesn't listen for any incoming requests, but they say if you'd like you can download from the zip they provide which has the updated version - link to conversation here https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/365

Answer (score 1):

Affected products and the status of mitigation have been posted in the Knowledge Article [Apache Log4j2 vulnerability](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363736&type=1).  They'll likely add more when/if they find more that have been affected.  Conversation also continues on the Trailblazer thread OP linked to in their original question.

To directly answer your question, it doesn't look like you'll be able to specifically see if your particular org has been affected outside of checking that table in the link to the KA.  A lot of them give the status as to what's being patched, others do say to contact Customer Support if you use that particular product (the current ones that say that are on-prem products).

That said, Salesforce has made it very clear that they will reach out to affected customers if they find evidence that their data has been accessed:

> As part of our continuous detection and monitoring systems, we have implemented detection and monitoring to alert for any potential exploitation attempts. If Salesforce becomes aware of unauthorized access to Customer Data, we will notify impacted customers without undue delay.